# My SQL statement is not returning my query back in alphabetical order

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-returning

I am trying to run a query on a database table and have it a return the results in alphabetical order, however when I run the following statement it returns everything in the same manner that it appears in the database. I am doing an order by the officegroup which from what I understand it should return the result order in alphabetical order.

```
SELECT 
    OfficeGroupID, OfficeGroup 
FROM 
    tblofficegroup 
INNER JOIN 
    tblRegion ON tblOfficeGroup.RegionID = tblRegion.RegionID 
WHERE 
    ISNULL(tblofficegroup.Hide, 0) = 0
    AND ISNULL(tblRegion.Hide, 0) = 0
    AND OfficeGroupID <> 18 --'Not Mapped'
ORDER BY 
    OfficeGroup  -- this should return it in alphabetical order but nogame.
                 -- I also tried passing the ASC command but neither worked
```

[image]

This is the table from the database, I am displaying the query on a webpage and it shows in the same order which is appears on in the table. I used `ASC` but no luck this is a string type (`varchar(32)`).

This is the function that makes the query for my webpage, I don't see anything wrong with it:

```
public static List<Market> GetMarketGroup()
{
    List<Market> regionList = new List<Market>();

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_constring))
    {
        StringBuilder sqlCommandBuilderTxt = new StringBuilder();

        sqlCommandBuilderTxt.Append("SELECT OfficeGroupID,OfficeGroup FROM tblofficegroup INNER JOIN tblRegion ON tblOfficeGroup.RegionID = tblRegion.RegionID WHERE ISNULL(tblofficegroup.Hide, 0) = 0 AND ISNULL(tblRegion.Hide, 0) = 0 AND OfficeGroupID <> 18 --'Not Mapped' ORDER BY OfficeGroup ASC ");

        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlCommandBuilderTxt.ToString(), connection);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                try
                {
                    Market market = new Market();// instance
                    market.MarketID = reader.GetInt32(0);
                    market.MarketGroup = reader.GetString(1);

                    regionList.Add(market);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    log.Error(ex);
                }
            }

            reader.Close();
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex);
        }
    }

    return regionList;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the results?

Comment: What is the actual data?  What are the results?  What is the type for that column?  `ORDER BY` does, in fact, order the data.  I suspect you're validating it wrong somehow.

Comment: and within what are you viewing the results

Comment: Do you see the same problem with the query `SELECT OfficeGroup FROM tblofficegroup ORDER BY OfficeGroup`? Also, what is the data type of the OfficeGroup column?

Comment: What about using: `ORDER BY OfficeGroup DESC` or rather `ORDER BY OfficeGroup ASC` - the Descending or Ascending should cover your needs?

Comment: @Leptonator op already said that s/he used `ASC`, though it's not like it's needed. Until we see the results that s/he is getting we are only speculating

Comment: What collation does the table/column have?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that that's the code you are using?, is there a chance that you are ordering by `OfficeGroupId`  instead?

Comment: I don't think the datatype is varchar(32) - your data is too long for that.

Comment: I have posted the table column which I am returning, I am loading the result on a webpage and they are ordered the same way it appears on the table I tried ASC but no luck

Comment: @phillyd the sample data fits in `VARCHAR(32).

Comment: loaded the function that queries for my webpage, I do not see anything that may override my Sql query

Comment: *sigh* with your posted code is clear that one issue is what @Kobi says in his answer, you are commenting the `ORDER BY`

Comment: Wow there it was, I moded my initial query but I pasted it on my query line and never say my query line had the comment...........smh

Comment: @Lamak, given that "South Carolina - Western Carolinas" is 34 characters long, I don't see how it could fit in a varchar(32).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be carefull with the tool (client) you use to execute the query.
 you are using `--` to comment a part of your statement, your client may wrap your query into a single line and then ignore the order by clause

consider using an other style of comment: `/* comment here */`